# How to solve $(x - 1)(x + 7) < 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried this:
\begin{align*}
                (x - 1)(x + 7) < 0
                &\iff x-1<0 \vee x+7<0\\
                &\iff x < 1 \vee x < -7\iff x\in(-7,1).
            \end{align*}
The thing though, is that I'm not sure if $ab<0 \implies a<0$ or $b<0$.

Comment: $ab<0 \implies (a<0 \wedge b > 0)$ or $(b<0 \wedge a > 0)$

Comment: Your final answer is correct because your mistakes canceled out. Your first $\iff$ and your last $\iff$ are both wrong: $x\in(-7,1)\iff x\lt1\text{ AND }x\gt-7$.

Comment: Use the table to determine the interval where the multiplication is negative which in this case -7 < x < 1

Answer (score 1):

A product $ab < 0$ if $a$ and $b$ have opposite signs.  When $a = x - 1$ and $b = x + 7$
$$(x - 1 > 0 \wedge x + 7 < 0) \vee (x - 1 < 0 \wedge x + 7 > 0)$$

Since $x - 1 > 0 \implies x > 1$ and $x + 7 < 0 \implies x < -7$, the statement $$x - 1 > 0 \wedge x + 7 < 0$$ is never true since it is not possible for a real number to be both greater than $1$ and less than $-7$.

Since $x - 1 < 0 \implies x < 1$ and $x + 7 > 0 \implies x > -7$, the statement $$x - 1 < 0 \wedge x + 7 > 0$$ is true when $-7 < x < 1$.

Hence, the solution set is $S = (-7, 1)$.

Another way to do the problem is to perform a line analysis.  Since $(x + 7)(x - 1) = 0$ when $x = -7$ or $x = 1$ and $(x + 7)(x - 1)$ is continuous, the sign of the product can change at the points $x = -7$ or $x = 1$.  We draw a number line with the points $x = -7$ and $x = 1$ marked as zeros.  We wish to determine the sign of the product $(x + 7)(x - 1)$ in the three intervals $(-\infty, -7), (-7, 1), (1, \infty)$.  To do so, we determine the signs of $x + 7$ and $x - 1$ in each of these intervals.  The term $x + 7$ is negative when $x < -7$, zero at $x = -7$, and positive when $x > -7$.  The term $x - 1$ is negative when $x < 1$, zero at $x = 1$, and positive when $x > 1$.  The sign of $(x + 7)(x - 1)$ in each interval is found by multiplying the signs of the factors $x + 7$ and $x - 1$ in that interval.

[image: line_analysis_for_(x+7)(x-1)<0]

Since we wish to determine where $(x + 7)(x - 1) < 0$, our solution set occurs where $(x + 7)(x - 1)$ is negative, which is the interval $(-7, 1)$.

Answer (score -1):

If we
[graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot++%28x-1%29%28x%2B7%29%3C0)
$\quad (x-1)(x+7)<0\quad$ we find that the parabola dips below zero between $-7$ and $1.\quad$ Simply put, this means it is correct to reason (as you did) that $\quad -7<x<1.\quad$ For integer solutions:
$\quad x\in\big\{-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0\big\}.$